# whether npoi nuget package accepts multiple colors in bar chart?

Tags: c#, bar-chart, npoi

Iam using dotnet version 6.0 dotnet core.
In this using C# NPOI nuget package i need to display the bar chart. where each bar should be in different colours inorder to differentiate them.

[image: this is the chart iam getting]

but iam expecting this type of chart

[image: where the bar chart with different colors in each bar]